# date() is not returning the expected value

Tags: javascript, php, date

In JavaScript I am using `(new Date("1985-05-01")).getTime();` to get the timestamp. The return value is **483753600000**.

In PHP I would like to return the year of that timestamp.

`date('Y', 483753600000);` returns **17299** but 1985 is expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In js the timestamp is in milliseconds in php in seconds.

Comment: date('Y', 483753600);

Comment: Note that in ECMAScript, the timestamp in `new Date("1985-05-01")` will be treated as UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's `getTime()` will return timestamp in **miliseconds**. PHP's `date()` function needs timestamp in **seconds**. So just divide it by **1000**:

```
date('Y', 483753600000 / 1000);
```

Comment: or take off the 0s o.O

Comment: @treyBake so.. divide it by / 1000? If that is a variable you'd need to convert it to a string and then cut last 3 characters. I don't see how is that any better than dividing

Comment: if it's a variable - current OP code != variable, so it's just an extra function call on something that doesn't look necessary

Comment: Well, if "current op code is not a variable" is your logic, then on his code there's this part "1985-05-01", he can just get the first part. why bother?

Comment: my point exactly^^

Comment: there's a reason he's doing it with two different languages.

Comment: Or, they're using JS as an example - they have a semi-ambigious sentence about using that timestamp, but it OP code example doesn't really convey usage of that timestamp

Comment: do you use javascript when looking at the date?

Comment: Depends, if client side, sure, if server-side then strictly php

Comment: and how do you do that? do you divide by 1000, or just manually delete zeroes from the end?

Comment: I make sure the logic is handled in relevant place so processing is done with as little logic possible. It should already be in the correct format for PHP to just process to begin with